# Video-out solution for an analog input

Tags: streaming, samsung-galaxy-nexus, video-out

I just got a Galaxy Nexus and love it. My current debacle is trying to figure out how to hook up my phone the display in my car which only has analog inputs (composite.) That worked perfectly with my old Droid Incredible as it did video out with composite through the microusb port. So i've been looking around for a solution and have found two viable options:

1. Get a digital to analog converter box which is around $50 off amazon and I already have the TV out cable for the Galaxy Nexus which works fine.
2. Find a product like apple TV for android where I can push the video to screen through an independent device but I'm not about to install a wireless router in the car.

Right now I feel the only real option seems the converter box but that seems far to cumbersome of a solution for what I'm trying to do. Anyone have a better idea or cheaper idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the [Digital to Analog converter off Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004FM3EF2). I tried the suggestion of onik but Galaxy Nexus has different 3.5mm jack than other Galaxy phones. I even tried my old HTC Incredible video out cable that goes through a modified microUSB but I didn't fit the Galaxy Nexus microusb port. There was no solution, that I could find, for an analog video other than the Digital to Analog converter. I installed it today and it works perfectly so I my phone mirrors to my head units display without a hitch.

The only trouble I ran into was powering the AC powered unit. I already had a DC to AC converter so I just plugged the AC power of the Video converter box in to the power converter box and hit it away in my glove box (many conversions, haha.) It looks seamless until you open the glove box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the Galaxy Nexus, but the older Galaxy models can output analog video through the headphone jack. The cable is similar to [Nokia CA-75U](http://www.mobilefun.co.uk/nokia-ca-75u-p13671.htm). Since the phone is a Google reference model without Samsung's addons, I'm not sure if this works, but I'd say it's worth a try.

Comment: I researched and tried that solution but the built in port doesn't support it. Good thought though, thanks!